# select rows with max date till current date as well as all the rows greater than today date

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

Suppose I've table

table :: *tbl_group_txn*

```
GroupName   Indvd_id    effective_date                  amount
--------------------------------------------------------------
JPN001      001         2015-11-13 00:00:00.000         70,000
JPN001      002         2015-11-13 00:00:00.000         80,000

JPN001      003         2015-11-16 00:00:00.000         90,000
JPN001      004         2015-11-16 00:00:00.000         75,000

JPN001      005         2015-11-29 00:00:00.000         100,000
JPN001      006         2015-11-29 00:00:00.000         125,000

CHN001      007         2015-11-29 00:00:00.000         60,000
CHN001      008         2015-11-15 00:00:00.000         70,000
CHN001      009         2015-11-15 00:00:00.000         70,000
CHN001      010         2015-11-18 00:00:00.000         40,000
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

My requirement is to get the rows under the same group with **MAX(effective_date )rows** for the date till today date and **all the rows greater than today date**.

In case of group **JPN001**, the rowid 3, 4 has max date till today date and rowid 5, 6 are rows having date greater than today date.

Similary in case of group **CHN001**, the rowid 10 has max date till today date and rowid 7 have date greater than today rate.

So the output will be ::

```
GroupName   Indvd_id    effective_date                  amount
--------------------------------------------------------------      
JPN001      003         2015-11-16 00:00:00.000         90,000
JPN001      004         2015-11-16 00:00:00.000         75,000

JPN001      005         2015-11-29 00:00:00.000         100,000
JPN001      006         2015-11-29 00:00:00.000         125,000

CHN001      007         2015-11-29 00:00:00.000         60,000
CHN001      010         2015-11-18 00:00:00.000         40,000
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

Please suggest how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first part of query, I get all rows with effective_date equal to MAX effective_date until today (with a fixed groupname) and with OR condition, I get all rows with effective_date > today date

Try this:

```
SELECT T.*
FROM mytable T
WHERE T.effective_date =
    (SELECT MAX(T2.effective_date)
    FROM mytable T2
    WHERE T2.groupname = T.groupname
    AND T2.effective_date <= GETDATE())
OR T.effective_date > GETDATE()
```

Go on [**SqlFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0604b/3/0)

Answer (score 0):

```
  In this select query i used DATEADD function in where clause to get all rows with max(effective_date)>today_date
 Try this:
            select *,effective_date 
            from #tbl_group_txn
            where effective_date>=dateadd(dd,datediff(dd,0,getdate()),-2)
            group by GroupName,Indvd_id,effective_date,amount
            order by Indvd_id
```